# Batch script error: "/ was unexpected at this time."

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wrote a little script to display every line of a text file with a random amount of pause between each of them:

```
SET pauseTime=10
SET maxval=20
SET minval=5
FOR /f %%j in (search1.txt) DO (
    SET pauseTime=%RANDOM% * (%maxval% - %minval% + 1) / 32768 + %minval%
    ECHO.%pauseTime%
    TIMEOUT %pauseTime%
    ECHO.%%j
)
```

Running this in cmd.exe gives me:
*C:\Users\Tim\Desktop>SET minval=5

/ was unexpected at this time.*

However, if I simply do:

```
FOR /f %%j in (search1.txt) DO (
    ECHO.%%j
)
```

I get all the lines printed with no errors

What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `/A` switch to your `SET` statement in order to do math operations. (I usually also have to remove any embedded spaces to get it to work properly as well.)

```
SET /A pausetime=%RANDOM%*(%maxval%)-%minval%)/32768+%minval%
```

The error you're getting is also caused by the batch processor not properly handing the parentheses within the `for` expression (the nested pair in the numeric expression). You can fix that by breaking that part of the expression out to a separate variable, and then using that variable in place of the portion within the parentheses:

```
SET pauseTime=10
SET maxval=20
SET minval=5
SET /A maxmin=%maxval% - %minval% + 1
FOR /f %%j in (search1.txt) DO (
  SET /A pauseTime=%RANDOM% * %maxmin% / 32768 + %minval%
  ECHO. %pauseTime%
  TIMEOUT %pauseTime%
  ECHO. %j%
)
```

Comment: As per your suggestion, I changed my `SET pauseTime=%RANDOM% * (%maxval% - %minval% + 1) / 32768 + %minval%` to `SET /A pauseTime=%RANDOM%*(%maxval%-%minval%)/32768+%minval%`. Now running the script gives me: _C:\Users\Tim\Desktop>SET minval=5      
    /32768+5 was unexpected at this time._

Comment: Substituting `%maxval%` and `%minval%` expressions with their numeric values gets rid of the errors...so I guess this issue has to do with some properties of percent expansion?

Comment: I see it. It's the nested parenthesis pair. I'll edit to include a fix.

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is because you use nested `( )` brackets which batch can't handle and causes your issue, you might need to split your pausetime calculation into 2 lines.

[see this article](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)

> The CMD shell statement does not use any great intelligence when evaluating parenthesis, so for example the command below will fail:
>
> IF EXIST MyFile.txt (ECHO Some(more)Potatoes)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned within the other answers, the problem is caused by the nested parenthesis.

Instead of avoiding them, you could also *escape* them by preceding `^` characters -- this works:

```
IF EXIST MyFile.txt (ECHO Some^(More^)Potatoes)
```

Without the caret `^` here, the command line interpreter takes the first `)` to close the first `(`.

---

However, applying the above escape technique to the code of the original question avoids the error message, but does *not* result in a working script, even if the inner `SET` is replaced by `SET /a` (as mentioned by @KenWhite), because you need to establish [delayed environment variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); otherwise, the displayed `pauseTime` value is always the initial one, `10`. The following fix works:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET pauseTime=10
SET maxval=20
SET minval=5
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f %%j in (search1.txt) DO (
    SET /a pauseTime=!RANDOM!*^(maxval-minval+1^)/32768+minval
    ECHO.!pauseTime!
    TIMEOUT !pauseTime!
    ECHO.%%j
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Herein, the `SETLOCAL` statement enables the delayed expansion before the `FOR` command executes. In the body of the `FOR` loop, `%pauseTime%` and `%RANDOM%` are replaced by `!pauseTime!` and `!RANDOM!`, respectively; those are the variables subject to delayed expansion (because of the enclosing `!!`), meaning that they are not (as usual) expanded immediately when the entire `FOR` command is parsed, but when it is executed. For the sake of legibility, I removed the `%%` from the other variables in the `SET /a` command since they are not required when the `/a` switch is present (note that there is also a `%` operator supported!!).

**Note:** After this script has run, `pauseTime` is reset to the initial value `10` as the `SETLOCAL`/`ENDLOCAL` block constitutes a new localised environment namespace; if you need the last value, replace line `ENDLOCAL` by `ENDLOCAL & SET pauseTime=%pauseTime%`; this utilises standard immediate expansion...

---

Nevertheless, since `minval` and `maxval` are constants in the script it is most intelligent to do the calculation `maxval-minval+1` outside of `FOR` once only, like @KenWhite suggested.